# Is this HTML legal, putting NOSCRIPT inside UL?

Tags: html, validation, tree, structure

Is this legal?

```
<UL>
  <NOSCRIPT>
    <LI>Foo
  </NOSCRIPT>
  <LI>Bar
</UL>
```

I ran it through a validator and it said no, but I'm not so sure it understands `NOSCRIPT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not valid but why you don't repeat your ul like this? One for Js and for no Js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>

 <noscript>
   <ul>
     <li>Foo</li>
     <li>Bar</li>
   </ul>
 </noscript>

<script>
   document.write("<ul><li>ShowIfJsAvailable</li></ul>");
</script>
```

Comment: Because nobody likes having to repeat their code. A script could easily just remove the first li after the fact.

Comment: Okay, you can also remove the first li. But you have to wait for DOMContentLoaded. Yes, i can understand it but not valid is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

It's not legal. A `UL` [may only contain](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) `LI` elements and [script-supporting elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-0) — and `NOSCRIPT` is not a script-supporting element. Although `NOSCRIPT` is treated differently based on the scripting environment, that special case is not relevant since it deals with the content model of `NOSCRIPT`, but the rules here pertain to the content model of `UL`.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off with designing the page to work without javascript first, and after that you may alter the page with javascript (or better yet, JQuery).

Previous answers already stated that noscript structure is not valid, so ditch that idea.

First write the page as it should look like without javascript, then modify the structure with javascript as you wish it would look like with the javascript on. Remove or add elements after the page is loaded - this is where JQuery and it's `$(document).ready()` really pays off!

Also your html-file will look much cleaner, and js-file only comes into play if scripts are enabled.

And do not use that document.write(), it will just complicate things.

Comment: It's not realistic to do what you are suggesting in my case. The `noscript` provides an alternate UI. To show that UI, then completely remove it once the page loads seems very user hostile since they would see it for a moment. (And no I'm not using `document.write()`.)

Comment: There are ways around it: Give the non-javascript elements a class and set that class to display:none right at the beginning of the javascript. We do such things all the time in our webshops.